# Correct way to track users and logout app

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus, logout

I am trying to code a native app with `social logins` as you can see the below image.

[image]

Now I'm able to authenticate users from my `FirstActivity` and sending the `authenticated users` to next `SecondActivity`.

Here comes my issue.

I have a single `logout` button on my `SecondActivity`

Now how do I know which `account` user `clicked` and how do I make them logout ?

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Huh?! You want to kill the oauth2 token of someone's device, just because they clicked a logout button in your app? Or have I completely misunderstood? I hope I have, because I'd not be impressed if a separate app invalidated my tokens, thus meaning I had to log in again.

Comment: No I don't mean way which breaks the rules.That's what I would like to know the correct implementation for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity make a string variable and set it to either facebook or either google + depending upon which the user picks to login. Pass in this variable as an extra with the intent to start the second activity.

So in your first activity you need something like this:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
myIntent.putExtra("id","FirstKeyValue");
myIntent.putExtra("name","SecondKeyValue");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In your second activity you need something like this to retrieve the value :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: @android_Muncher- Thanks for your reply. Yes even I too like this implemetation but is the right way of doing this ?